# Combining Functions in Excel

Tags: excel, function

I have a list of addresses in Excel. They are all the same, except for one difference - some have "US" at the end, while others end in a zip code. Two examples below:

***142 N. Birchwood Louisville KY 40206 US***

***3937 Ludlow Street Philadelphia PA 19104***

I am trying to extract the zip code for all the addresses in another column. To achieve this, I did a 2 step process.

`=SUBSTITUTE(N2, "US", "")` to delete US from every address.

`=RIGHT(P2, 6)` to extract the 6 characters from the right to get the 5 digit zip code)

The problem is that these functions are in two different columns and done separately. How do I combine these functions into one to get rid of the extra step?

Thank you!

Comment: Careful! What if you have an address `Userman Street`, or `Massachusetts`? The substitute will remove US from there.  Also, assuming `P2` is your Substitute formula...`=RIGHT(=SUBSTITUTE(N2, "US", ""),6)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be enough to do the job:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="US",MID(A1,LEN(A1)-7,5),RIGHT(A1,5))
```

The idea is that you should check for "US" only on the last part of the string. Thus, you have two options, depending on the result - either `RIGHT(A1,5)` or `MID(A1,LEN(A1)-7,5)`:

[image]

Comment: again, thanks so much! perfect function and the explanation is very helpful